# How to inform the models of the api version?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, api

Currently, I use `api-versions` gem which nicely creates api routes and contains the version information in the request HEAD.

However, sometimes the models need to know the api version being used.  Example, validations.  Let's say presence of username needs to be validated on any version >= 2, but not on versions < 2.

In the Controller layer, it's easy to retrieve the api version by parsing out the appropriate request HEAD.  But what's the best way to communicate that version number to the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about defining a psudo-attribute in the model class with validators acting conditionally

```
class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :api_version
    validates_presence_of :username, :if => :api_version > 2
    ...
```

Then from the controller, set the api_version on the model before saving etc

```
@someModel = SomeModel.new(params[:some_model])
@someModel.api_version = <<extracted from HEAD>>
@someModel.save!
```

Comment: This is exactly what I also thought of.  Good to have a 2nd opinion.  Thanks!